# c# razor generator compile error with NancyFx project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nancy, razorgenerator

First time ask question here hope sb can help me.

Background:
I am using Vs2017 creating a c# mvc program with NancyFX based on .NET 4.6 . 
The program works find but I want to use razor generator to compile views (.cshtml)
I install razor generator and generated .cs for all views.

When compile I got tons of errors saying: 
"The name 'Href' does not exist in the current context" in all generated.cs files.

If I remove first line "@inherits nancyRazorViewBase" from _layoutDefault I got error message "type expect".

Had been stuck in this for whole day.

Thanks for any tips.

------ update ---------

Now I am sure its sth wrong with the configuration, most likely web.config.

From the error message "Href ...." in generated.cs it says 'Href' can NOT be found. It is actually under assembly "system.web.webPages" . See iamge below:
[defination for Href](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpXwo.png)

in index.generated.cs this assemble was referenced & using System.web.webpages. But you can see compile error.  [261 compile errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a283P.png)

relevant setting in web.configure :[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTGdR.png)

Comment: Probably a good idea to share your code here. Try to pair it down to a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks Alan. Upload some configuration which I think might have problem.

Comment: Yeah, don;t post images of code - always post the text of the code into your answers. I can't help you with this question, it is outside my field, but I was reviewing your post as a new poster to ensure you learn the write way of doing things. People don't like code images, they want to be able to copy code into their environments.

Comment: Hi Alan, I was posting code in text format but somehow I wont be able to submit that is why I took screenshot.  Thanks.